# Why does Jesus tell the disciples to buy swords?

Tags: jesus, luke, layers-of-meaning

[Luke 9:3](http://esv.to/Luke9.3) and [Luke 22:36](http://esv.to/Luke22.36) seem to form an *inclusio*. In chapter nine, Jesus instructs the Twelve, "Take nothing for the journey—no staff, no bag, no bread, no money, no extra tunic." But in [chapter 22](http://esv.to/Luke20), he tells them, "But now if you have a purse, take it, and also a bag; and if you don’t have a sword, sell your cloak and buy one."

What is being conveyed by this? It is strange that Jesus tells them to buy swords, but that two is enough. And just a couple verses later in 22:49-51 he has them put them away their swords. Why did Jesus have them buy swords then?

Comment: Related question on [christianity.se]: [Why did Jesus tell His disciples to buy a sword?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7121) (Which probably needs serious help; if anything useful comes out of this question...)

Comment: @Caleb: why does it need serious help?

Comment: @Wikis: My quick review before cross-linked shown one answer that makes some sense and might be right but has no references backing it up, one that has tons of references but I couldn't make out what the main point really was, and one that was just thrown out there. Maybe I should have just said "help" rather than "serious help".

Comment: @Caleb: thanks. I like the accepted answer (obviously) but take your point about references.

Comment: I wonder if there is a third way besides these answers, buy I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: This might also be applied not simply to the disciples but to Israel's history in general.

Comment: When he told them that He was telling them to buy a bible, that would be their weapon of warfare... Eph. 6:17

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I always have read that is that Luke 22:36 is meant to be taken metaphorically: "Dangerous times are coming and you must be prepared."  But as usual, the disciples don't get it.  A possible parallel situation is:

> Now they had forgotten to bring bread, and they had only one loaf with them in the boat. And he cautioned them, saying, “Watch out; beware of the leaven of the Pharisees and the leaven of Herod.” And they began discussing with one another the fact that they had no bread. And Jesus, aware of this, said to them, “Why are you discussing the fact that you have no bread? Do you not yet perceive or understand? Are your hearts hardened? Having eyes do you not see, and having ears do you not hear? And do you not remember? When I broke the five loaves for the five thousand, how many baskets full of broken pieces did you take up?” They said to him, “Twelve.” “And the seven for the four thousand, how many baskets full of broken pieces did you take up?” And they said to him, “Seven.” And he said to them, “Do you not yet understand?”—Mark 8:14-21 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Mark+8/))

In that case, Jesus wanted his disciples to think of leaven (and bread) in a metaphorical sense, but they re-interpreted his statement to be somehow related to their failure to bring lunch.  Here, Jesus took a moment to turn the confusion into a teaching opportunity.

But in the upper room, Jesus didn't take (or have) the time to correct them.  Perhaps part of the reason is that he knew what Peter would do when Jesus was arrested:

> And when those who were around him saw what would follow, they said, “Lord, shall we strike with the sword?” And one of them struck the servant of the high priest and cut off his right ear. But Jesus said, “No more of this!” And he touched his ear and healed him.—Luke 22:49-51 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Luke+22/))

Presumably if Peter knew that Jesus wasn't talking about real swords, he would have left his in the room or known not to use it against the guards.  As for *why* Jesus was willing to have Peter remain in the dark, I'm not sure the text tells us.  My speculation is that he wanted the disciples to think about it later and realize that his Kingdom was not established with swords and spears.

---

Recall that Luke also wrote the history of the early church (Acts) as it spread across the Roman Empire.  Swords come into play [only twice](http://legacy.esvbible.org/search/sword/Acts/):

> About that time Herod the king laid violent hands on some who belonged to the church. He killed James the brother of John with the **sword**, and when he saw that it pleased the Jews, he proceeded to arrest Peter also. This was during the days of Unleavened Bread. And when he had seized him, he put him in prison, delivering him over to four squads of soldiers to guard him, intending after the Passover to bring him out to the people.
>   (Acts 12:1-4 [ESV](http://legacy.esvbible.org/Acts+12/))

and:

> About midnight Paul and Silas were praying and singing hymns to God, and the prisoners were listening to them, and suddenly there was a great earthquake, so that the foundations of the prison were shaken. And immediately all the doors were opened, and everyone's bonds were unfastened. When the jailer woke and saw that the prison doors were open, he drew his **sword** and was about to kill himself, supposing that the prisoners had escaped.
>   (Acts 16:25-27 [ESV](http://legacy.esvbible.org/Acts+16/))

To Luke's readers, the idea that a kingdom could be established with two swords would be preposterous. If Jesus were speaking literally, we'd expect [the detail to be paid off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun) literally.  And yet, the only time his followers used a sword was against the high priest's servant and Jesus clearly discouraged further violence.  Luke likely included the saying about buying swords to demonstrate to his Roman readers that the church could not be a military threat to the Empire.

Comment: I, too, have noticed how frequently Jesus and His disciples were on different wavelengths, so to speak. Another parallel situation is in John 4, where Jesus said to His disciples who had just encouraged Him to eat, "I have food to eat that you do not know about," which caused the disciples to wonder to themselves, "Hmm. Who gave Him food? Didn't we leave Him here at the well to rest up while we did a little grocery shopping?" Jesus did not have to hear them physically to know what they were thinking, so He said, "My food is to do my Father's will and accomplish His work" (cf. Ma 4:4).

Comment: In Mark 8:14-21 there is a clear textual indication that the yeast and bread are metaphors: "leaven of the Pharisees" makes the metaphoric interpretation the only logical one.  What *textual* indication do you have that the swords of Luke 22:36 are metaphorical? I see none, and I instead see a *very* clear indication they are not: the disciples are clearly pointing to literal swords, and Jesus' reply that they are sufficient confirms quite clearly that he *was, in fact,* referring to physical, literal swords.

Comment: @iconoclast: I've expanded on my answer.  The immediate context does indicate literal swords, but it's impossible for me to fit that into the broad context of Luke's narrative.  I'd encourage you to try your hand at an alternate answer if you disagree.

Answer (score 3):

The important part of the passage is where Jesus says that he will be executed, numbered amongst the transgressors. The immediate result is that the situation will change. Whereas before they benefited from Christ's faith, NOW they have to provide their own resources through faith.

Missionaries will have their ministry confirmed by the turning up of finances, training etc.

> Now they had forgotten to bring bread, and they had only one loaf with them in the boat. And he cautioned them, saying, “Watch out; beware of the leaven of the Pharisees and the leaven of Herod.” And they began discussing with one another the fact that they had no bread. And Jesus, aware of this, said to them, “Why are you discussing the fact that you have no bread? Do you not yet perceive or understand? Are your hearts hardened? Having eyes do you not see, and having ears do you not hear? And do you not remember? When I broke the five loaves for the five thousand, how many baskets full of broken pieces did you take up?” They said to him, “Twelve.” “And the seven for the four thousand, how many baskets full of broken pieces did you take up?” And they said to him, “Seven.” And he said to them, “Do you not yet understand?”—**Mark 8:14-21 (ESV)**

God was with Jesus! That's to understand!

> **John 3:1-2 NET** Now a certain man, a Pharisee named Nicodemus, who was a member of the Jewish ruling council, came to Jesus at night and said to him, “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher who has come from God. For no one could perform the miraculous signs that you do unless God is with him.”

Similarly, the teachings He gave them needed to be buttressed by what they would be given from Scripture :

> **Isaiah 55:1 NET** “Hey, all who are thirsty, come to the water!
>   You who have no money, come!
>   Buy and eat!
>   Come! Buy wine and milk
>   without money and without cost!
>
> **Hebrews 4:12 NET** For the word of God is living and active and sharper than any double-edged sword, piercing even to the point of dividing soul from spirit, and joints from marrow; it is able to judge the desires and thoughts of the heart.

................

> So, Jesus had said "Do not acquire gold, or silver, or copper for your money belt" (Matt. 10:9).  But, an interesting change of teaching by Jesus can be found in Luke when later on in his ministry he told the disciples to take a purse, a bag, and a sword.
>
> "And He said to them, “When I sent you out without purse and bag and sandals, you did not lack anything, did you?” And they said, “No, nothing.” 36 And He said to them, “But now, let him who has a purse take it along, likewise also a bag, and let him who has no sword sell his robe and buy one. 37 “For I tell you, that this which is written must be fulfilled in Me, ‘And He was numbered with transgressors’; for that which refers to Me has its fulfillment.” 38 And they said, “Lord, look, here are two swords.” And He said to them, “It is enough,” (Luke 22:35-38).

..................

> Why the change? It was because soon the disciples would be without Jesus and they would have to rely on God's provision through people, not through Christ, during their upcoming gospel work.

[[Source](http://carm.org/pastors-paid)]

Answer (score 3):

Yeshua's had taught his disciples to not resist an evil doer.

> But I tell you not to resist an evil person. But whoever slaps you on your right cheek, turn the other to him also (Mt. 5:39 NKJV).

This instruction did not change though he instructed them to buy swords; in fact, as we shall see, it plays perfectly into how he demonstrates and cooperates with Gods plan at this critical moment in his life. The swords merely help set the stage for this remarkable act of submission to his Father's will.

Luke 22:35-38 (NKJV) reads:

> 35    And He said to them, "When I sent you without money bag, knapsack, and sandals, did you lack anything?" So they said, "Nothing."
>   36  Then He said to them, "But now, he who has a money bag, let him take it, and likewise a knapsack; and he who has no sword, let him sell his garment and buy one.
>   37  **For I say to you that this which is written must still be accomplished in Me: 'And He was numbered with the transgressors.'** For the things concerning Me have an end."
>   38  So they said, "Lord, look, here are two swords." And He said to them, "It is enough."

Here we find **the only reason** given for instructing them to take swords, ie. **to fulfill that which was spoken of him: 'And He was numbered with the transgressors.'**

How then is Prophecy fulfilled.
Matthew 26:51-56 (NKJV) reads:

> 51    And suddenly, one of those who were with Jesus stretched out his hand and drew his sword, struck the servant of the high priest, and cut off his ear.
>   52  But Jesus said to him, **"Put your sword in its place, for all who take the sword will perish by the sword.**
>   53  **Or do you think that I cannot now pray to My Father, and He will provide Me with more than twelve legions of angels?**
>   54  **How then could the Scriptures be fulfilled, that it must happen thus?"**
>   55  In that hour Jesus said to the multitudes, "Have you come out, as against a robber, with swords and clubs to take Me? I sat daily with you, teaching in the temple, and you did not seize Me.
>   56  But **all this was done that the Scriptures of the prophets might be fulfilled**." Then all the disciples forsook Him and fled.

We see here how the sword helped set the stage and Yeshua's rebuke of Peter, makes it clear that it was never Yeshua's intent that the swords be used in his defense. He says, "Put your sword in its place, for all who take the sword will perish by the sword . . . **How then could the Scriptures be fulfilled, that it must happen thus?"** We see Yeshua's clear intent was to demonstrate that he will not allow power on earth to come to his defense.  Scriptures must be fulifilled; It must happen this way.

We see also in his rebuke of Peter an even more profound indication of Yeshua intent.  He says, "do you think that I cannot now pray to My Father, and He will provide Me with more than twelve legions of angels?"
The swords which man can see, are a faint earthly parallel of the army of heaven which man cannot see, **neither of which he calls upon or allows to come to his defense.**

When the picture is all put together, we see that Yeshua **allowed** himself to be taken instead of being defended by either earthly force or heavenly force so that what was prophesied of him would be fulfilled--for "This that is written MUST STILL BE ACCOMPLISHED IN ME"--so he is taken prisoner and numbered among transgressors.

Take the swords out of the picture then he has no opportunity to not allow them to use them and no opportunity to point out that he could have called upon His Father to deliver him.  Much would be missing from our knowledge.

Comment: Just a note, Rom 13:4 teaches that the government, not individuals, are God's ministers who bear the sword, to avenge wrath on those who practice evil.

Comment: For rulers hold no terror for those who do right, but for those who do wrong. Do you want to be free from fear of the one in authority? Then do what is right and you will be commended. 4For the one in authority is God’s servant for your good. But if you do wrong, be afraid, for rulers do not bear the sword for no reason. 
--------------- It seems to me that if the above doesn't hold for the governing authority, how can the rest be applicable. If you live in a government that rewards people for doing wrong, should you still submit?

Comment: @user2027 "Take the swords out of the picture then he has no opportunity to not allow them to use them and no opportunity to point out that he could have called upon His Father to deliver him. Much would be missing from our knowledge." Did you mean "no opportunity TO ALLOW them"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question requires a little B.C.E/C.E knowledge of history. As you may or may not be aware, from about 332 B.C.E to roughly 135 C.E, the Israelite world was under Greek/Roman rule. This period is historically known as the Hellenization period,where Greek/ Roman influence began to take over much of the Arabic, European,and Asia minor regions and cultures of that day. Among these were the Jewish cultures, who,in compliance with Greek/Roman rule,began adapting much of the ancient Greek/Roman theologies and philosophies into their own beliefs. One of these philosophical movements, called Cynicism,  (founded by The Greek philosopher Diogenes), was a movement that began evangelism,where cynics would travel from town to town,teaching and preaching for people to abandon their fleshly desire for fame,fortune,and pleasure, for a life of virtuous living. These influences soon made there way into Christ era Judaism/Early Christianity,and,no doubt, is where Jesus acquired this inspiration. Also during this period, there were many Jewish Revolts against the Roman empire. Many of these revolts were  headed by proclaimed " Messiahs" of the Jewish community( Judas,son of the bandit chief Hezekiah, Judas the Galilean,and Simon of Perea, to name a few). Messiah is a Greek derivative of the Hebrew word" Moshiach ", which simply means "anointed one". "The Messiah" was in reference to the Hellenistic Jewish expectation for a man who would be anointed by "Yahweh"(God) to free the Jews forever from foreign rule,and restore back the land to the Israelite. This was always assumed to be accomplished by force. Many revolting Jews were encouraged by their Rebel leaders(or Messiahs), to use violent force when deemed necessary to accomplish the cause.This is also why Jesus is quoted in  Mathew 10:34 as saying "Do not suppose that I have come to bring peace to the earth. I did not come to bring peace, but a sword". Modern day teachings of interpretation for this scripture and others(like your Luke 22 scripture)
 suggest a non literal approach with spiritual warfare connotations. However during the early Christian era,these scriptures were taken quite literally.

Comment: This answer would be greatly strengthened by citing sources.

Comment: He also talks about using the sword to divide the sheep. I think it's clear when you view that in context with the rest of his life that he is talking in metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

**Why does Jesus tell the disciples to buy swords?**

Jesus did not have protection in mind, for he was aware what was to take place on the last night of his life on earth. Instead Jesus wanted to teach his followers a vital lesson, not to resort to  violence when confronted by an  angry crowd or an armed mob.

Luke 22:52  (NASB)

> 52 "Then Jesus said to the chief priests and officers of the temple
>   and elders who had come against Him, “Have you come out with swords
>   and clubs as you would against a robber?

Feeling incensed by the injustice,  Peter struck with  his sword and cut off the ear ,of the  high priest's slave, Jesus immediately  commanded Peter:

Matthew 26:52 NASB

> “Put your sword back into its place; for all those who take up the
>   sword shall perish by the sword.

On that last night of his life , Jesus  wanted to impress  to  them, that  he was giving himself voluntary in fulfillment of the prophesies and did not intend to resort to the sword . Also Jesus wanted to point out to his disciples that due to their  preaching, they would also face opposition and  danger to  their life , and hazardous  situations similar to his, with armed resistance .

**The object lesson is : "for all those who take up the sword shall
 perish by the sword."( Mat. 26:52)**

Answer (score 0):

#### *Why does Jesus tell the disciples to buy swords?*

These words by Christ are not to be understood literally, that is, that he would have his disciples furnish themselves with swords since he would never have said, as he does afterward, that two were sufficient.  It’s absurd to believe that two small swords could be enough for the defense of over eleven men.  Nor would this have forbidden Peter to use one of them, as he did shortly thereafter in the Garden.<sup>1</sup>

Rather, his meaning seems to be that wherever the disciples had previously enjoyed a friendly welcome, where a door was opened to them for the preaching of the Gospel, they would now face many adversaries.  Some of this resistance would emerge from the most powerful offices in the land, and they would thereafter (following Christ’s crucifixion) encounter great persecution, rage and violence.

The subsequent intensity would lead them to believe they would stand in need of swords to defend themselves.  They must seek shelter from the future onslaught just as we read in the Book of Acts. The phrase is expressive of the danger they would be exposed to, and of their need for protection.

It was therefore wrong for any of them to be disputing and quarrelling about superiority when this would be their forlorn, destitute, and afflicted condition.  Indeed, they were about to witness some of this affliction and distress beginning with Christ himself – as He was led away to death by torture:

> **Luke 22:38**: "[The disciples] said, 'Lord, look, here are two swords.' And He said to them, 'It is enough.'"

This verse seems to be yet another instance where the disciples were oblivious to the deeper meaning conveyed by Christ. Jesus was surely focused on the horrific ordeal that lay immediately before Him.  Observing that they missed His point entirely, He puts the matter to rest by simply adding, “It is enough,” perhaps the ancient equivalent of the more modern, “Well, whatever.”

This last comment by Christ is an indication that the disciples misunderstood His application to their future without Him, one of impoverishment and miserable circumstances requiring their every ounce of self-preservation for survival.

<sup>1</sup> Gill, John. *John Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible* (1690-1771). John Gill (23 November 1697 – 14 October 1771) was an English Baptist pastor, biblical scholar, and theologian who held to a firm Calvinistic soteriology.

Comment: nice try, but why DID Jesus say to get swords? This was the core of the Q, not what the disciples thought or didn't understand. "his meaning seems to be that" is really an opinion then.

Comment: FYI, I think think this answer nailed it. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/why-does-jesus-tell-the-disciples-to-buy-swords/3975#3975

Comment: @user48152 Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Recall Mt 10:9-11/16-22.  The Disciples went out penniless and defenseless, despite the warning of future persecution, with the protection and provision of God. Yet on the eve of Jesus' betrayal and death He gives the disciples a different charge; "You will need provisions and a means of self defense".  To say Jesus is speaking metaphorically is isogesis and not consistent with His plain words. That he heals the servant of the High priest only reveals that the swords were not to protect Him, despite Peters zeal to do so.
Provision of clothing, money and self defense are practical matters in a world where Jesus is not physically present as the "bridegroom".  I believe that the plainest interpretation is that all normal provisions and protections may be needed AFTER the bridegroom is taken from them. We see no instances of the Apostles employing weapons in their "Acts", but this does not mean protection from everyday trials of life were beneath their spirituality. We do see instances of robust use of spiritual gifts and power to treat with evildoers such as Ananias and Saphhira. Rather than to over spiritualize the text, let it stand as a common sense charge to the disciples (and us) to prepare for our journey in this world with the everyday provisions common to all mankind. We don't use the sword as a weapon of attack as Jesus corrects Peter in the Garden, but it can be used in self defense, as Nehemiah instructed the builders of the wall of Jerusalem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Consider this passage a warning about the future. God will provide and protect them. Jesus was warning them that showing a lack of confidence in his teachings would undercut their efforts to spread the gospel and they would have to defend themselves in this regard. The two swords simply shows that the meaning of what he said was not understood.